# JavaScript regex test function always returns false after the first true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm writing a small function for validating character input in a `textarea`.
My regex allows only characters A-Z, full stops and commas.

The validation returns `true` only when I type for the first time. Then it returns only `false`, no matter what character I type. It's pretty confusing.
Can you help?

Below is the function.

```js
var _checkRemainingCharsWords = function() {
  $('#textarea-content').on('input', function() {
    var regExNumbers = /^[a-zA-Z,.]+$/;
    var strTest = regExNumbers.test(this.value);
    if (strTest) {
      console.log("valid", this.value);

    } else {
      console.log("wrong", this.value);
      return false;
    }
  });
};

_checkRemainingCharsWords();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea-content" ></textarea>
```

Comment: works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ssvkt3fs/1/

Comment: Did you run `_checkRemainingCharsWords` this function?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA, he said he is getting false.

Comment: it works but I need to type back and remove the wrong char. How I can avoid the typing of wrong chars when found?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block `key`, you need to either use `keydown` function and on invalid character, use `event.preventDefault()` or use `keyup` and replace all invalid characters. For demo, I have added a simple regex to replace numbers.

```js
var _checkRemainingCharsWords = function() {
  $('#textarea-content').on('keyup', function() {
    var regExNumbers = /^[a-zA-Z,.]+$/;
    var strTest = regExNumbers.test(this.value);
    if (this.value) {
      if (strTest) {
        console.log("valid", this.value);
      } else {
        console.log("wrong", this.value);
        var numReg = /\d/gi;
        this.value = this.value.replace(numReg,'');
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
};

_checkRemainingCharsWords();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea-content"></textarea>
```

Comment: It works well if I add a number. I just need to allow only the above characters specified in the regular expression. How can I exclude the rest of the special chars?

Comment: Actually it wasn't right. Still need to find a solution for it :/